# Is Int a category of all integers?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

**Proposition**: each type is a category itself.

Ex: `Int` is a category of all `integers` under Hask.

Is that the case?

If so, what are homomorphisms in the category of `Int`, or all possible morphism from `Int->Int`?
How can define it?

---

**edited**:

```
--In the category of Hask

--Imagine, I have Str category just of strings under Hask, then:

Obj(Str) is Singelton
Hom (Str) is each string
Composition operation is (++) operator --in Haskell
```

Comment: Whatever you want them to be, as long as they follow the laws.  There are many choices. Try to come up with one.

Comment: The question seems to lack context. Depending on the context, the notion of "type" could vary quite considerably. Such a proposition could mean anything dependeng on what you mean by "type". There are a lot of different formal systems (type theories), each with their own slightly different notion of `type`. Are you talking about the messy reality of Haskell types? Or some neat, cleaned up academic type theory that approximates Haskell's types? Or maybe about types from HoTT?

Comment: And... do you want to code something? Of course, as soon as you attach "haskell" tag to it, questions about categories, Kan extensions, Grothendieck fibrations and sheaf cohomology immediately become practical programming questions, but still...

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Oh your "singleton category" is called a `Monoid`.  There are a few moniods for `Integer`, namely `Sum`, `Product`, `Min`, and `Max` (and you can define more).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "type" and "is a category". If you take any concrete type in a programming language, there are only countably many possible values of that type, so you can just take the set of all values, and say that it is a discrete category `C`, which has nothing but the identity morphisms.

Integers can be considered a category in many different ways:

- (Z, +, 0) is a group, therefore a special kind of groupoid with a single object (`Obj(C) = {*}` is the only object, each integer is a morphism, `0` is the identity morphism, `+` is the composition).
- (Z, <=) is a partially ordered set, posets are special very simple categories. Morphisms are just structureless arrows between elements, with one arrow for each pair of integers `(a, b)` such that `a <= b`. Reflexivity `a <= a` are the identity morphisms. Transitivity is the composition.
- (Z, |) (divisibility relation) is again a poset, arrows again simply indicate that some integer divides some other integer: `a|b`. Again, `refl_a = a|a` are the identity morphisms, the fact that if `a|b` and `b|c` then `a|c` gives the composition.

If you are interested only in the *type* `Int`, you can also build 
many different categories out of it:

- The simplest example: take `Int` as the only object, take the identity function on `Int` as the only morphism, done. That's a category, usually called `1`.
- Somewhat less degenerate construction: the monoid of endomorphisms on `Int`. Again take `Int` as the only object of your category. Take as `Hom[Int, Int]` the set of all terminating total functions which are implementable in Haskell **(1)** , define the composition on this hom-set as the ordinary composition of functions.
- You can play with this construction a little: for example, you can consider partial functions, or only invertible functions (that would give a group of automorphisms, and therefore a very simple groupoid).

There are many other ways to define a category which "bears some relationship to `Int`". It depends on what you want to do with it.

**On your 'edit':** That's just a special case of every monoid being a category with a single object. For integers, you can immediately build a handful of monoids:

- `(Int, +, 0)` (`a+b` is the composition, `0` is the identity)
- `(Int, *, 1)` (`a*b` is the composition, `1` is the identity)
- `(Int, bitwise Xor, 0)` (`a xor b` is the composition, `0` the identity)
- `(Int, bitwise And, 0xF...F)`, analogous
- ... (almost any other bitwise binary operation)

You obtain a category from a monoid always by the same construction: given a monoid `(M, op, zero)`, take a structureless point `{*}` as the single object, take `M` as the set of morphisms, take `zero` as the identity, `op` as composition, and you obtain a category. This is simply because monoids are *by definition* the same as categories with a single object.

**EDIT**:

**(1)** Oh, wait, you'd need rather something like the equivalence classes modulo extensionality, otherwise even `f . id` isn't the same as `f`, and associativity wouldn't work either, even without the "help" of integer-overflows and other nasty things that happen on a real computer. Notice that the undecidability of properties like *"does it terminate for all input values?"* and *"do these two functions return the same result for all inputs?"* does not break the well-definedness.

Comment: Don't forget the discrete category, `|Int|`, where each integer is an object and there are only identity morphisms. We use this category when we work with the type `Int -> *`.

Comment: @pigworker: Isn't it covered by the first "disclaimer" sentence that nearly anything can be considered a discrete category, as long as it is not too large or otherwise too inchoate, and as long as you are willing to forget all the structure and pulverize everything into discrete dust?

Comment: Probably. I was in a hurry and clocked the bullet points. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

In your edit you've identified monoids, which are categories with one object, where the hom-set is the elements of the monoid.

There are also categories with at most one arrow between any two objects, and these are the *partial orders*. For example, on `Int`:

- The objects are the integers.
- There's an arrow from `x` to `y` exactly when `x` is less than or equal to `y`.
- Composition is just the transitivity property.
- Identity is reflexivity.

The degenerate case is the partial orders with zero arrows between any two objects (except identity arrows), the so-called *discrete categories*.